# Why minimize the KL divergence from data to the model instead of KL divergence of model to data?

Tags: machine-learning, kullback-leibler

When minimizing the KL divergence in machine learning, why the expression of KL is from data to model, instead of from model to data ?

Comment: not sure if you're referring to variational inference, but if you are, minimizing the kl divergence in the other direction is called expectation propagation

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482362/kl-divergence-pq-vs-qp/482374#482374

Answer (score 1):

One explanation is that this is what maximizing (log) likelihood gives you.

Suppose you have observed coin tosses $y_i \in \{0,1\}, i=1,\dots,n$ and wish to estimate the coin flip probability $p$. Maximizing likelihood is 
\begin{align*}
\arg \max_p \prod_{i=1}^n p^{y_i}(1-p)^{1-y_i} &= \arg\max_p \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \log p + (1-y_i)\log(1-p) \\
&= \arg\max_p -\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \log \frac{1}{p} + (1-y_i)\log \frac{1}{1-p} \\
&= \arg\min_p \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \log \frac{y_i}{p} + (1-y_i)\log \frac{1-y_i}{1-p} \\
&= \arg\min_p \sum_{i=1}^n \text{KL}(y_i,p)
\end{align*}
since $0 \log 0 = 0$.